# Problems with wordpress redirects of a site inside a site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been digging through all sorts of tutorials on this and messing with a bunch of multisite/htaccess stuff. Let me give you my scenario and see if someone can tell me what in the world to do to make it work.

I have a wordpress site in a folder
/mudmin6
That site is mudministry.org

I have another wordpress site (totally separate) in a subfolder of that site
/mudmin6/userspice
That site is userspice.com

Ideally I would like to be able to access this site by typing either of these two things...

mudministry.org/userspice
or
userspice.com

So far, that works. However, I can't do something that's really important.

I can't type, say
userspice.com/forums and get to my forums. I get an internal server error. The only way to get to the forums is to go all the way back to mudministry.org/userspice/forums

Can someone tell me what needs to change in my .htacces, wp-config, or wordpress dashboard to make this happen (and in what subfolder to make these changes?)

.htaccess for mudministry.org

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

.htaccess for userspice

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /userspice/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /userspice/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I know that there are a lot of people who will say why do I need to do this?  I need to do it for a grant we have.  The initial domain must be accessible by mudministry.org/userspice but it's also really annoying that I can't type userspice.com/anything and get to any of my pages.

Comment: Can you tell me what the internal server error is?   Some detail of the internal server error should show up in in your error log.    This is where I would start

Comment: It's basically a 404 error.  When my site is configured like this, any page that can't be found when accessed from userspice.com/dfssf shows up error 500. Any page that can't be found via mudministry.org/userspice/dfssf shows up as 404

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the internal Proxy [P], I have not done this before,  but let me know if this works.

You will want to put this into the root .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(userspice)/(.*)$ http://userspice.com/$2 [NC,P]
```

You may also want to use [ProxyPassReverse](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) to make sure any redirects are done as you expect. This may not work,  depending on how you have relative and absolute urls used in your application.   But if you dont mind that when the user starts to browse around in the userspice directory,  that they are switched over to the userspice.com domain,  this could work

Comment: I think you're getting REALLY close.  I added that line and now I don't get internal server errors anymore when I do userspice.com/anything. It just redirects me to the homepage.  Can you think of anything I can add there that will let it grab the routes that the install at /userspice has?  Everything else is working perfectly.   I'll check out proxy pass reverse too, but I think this just needs an htaccess fix.

Comment: perhaps try  ProxyPassReverse?  mentioned above.  I havent used it before,  but it seems to try to address it for you   ProxyPassReverse  "/userspice/" "http://userspice.com/"  .     In order to get further,  I would visit Apache's ProxyPass documentation and mess around with those options until you find the correct combination

Comment: I'm willing to give it a shot. The userspice site is getting a ton of traffic at the moment and I'm a little reluctant to break it. It usually quiets down on the weekends so I'll give it a shot during some off hours. Thank you!

Comment: I'm on a shared server, so I don't think ProxyPassReverse is an option

Comment: I tried making some of those changes and hostgator froze my account for all the redirects.  I think I have another strategy...I'll edit the question.

Comment: The code editor is freaking out and not letting me format my code. I'll have to ask a new question.